# vue.js - Implementing Auth0 example in my project gives me _vm.login is not a function(…)

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, auth0

I have to say first.. i'm VERY new to both VUE and Auth0 so my guess.. there are some logical error causing this, and is pretty easy to understand for a more experienced VUE developer.

i'm getting a : _vm.login is not a function(…) when clicking the "Login" button..

I think i'll step right to my code here :

**MAIN.JS**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import store from "./store"

import App from './components/App.vue'
import Login from './components/Login.vue'
import Home from './components/Home.vue'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
  { path: '/', component: Login },
  { path: '/home', component: Home }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
})

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  store,
  data() {
    return {
      authenticated: false,
      secretThing: '',
      lock: new Auth0Lock('xxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxx.eu.auth0.com')
    }
  },
  ready() {
    var self = this;

this.authenticated = checkAuth();

this.lock.on('authenticated', (authResult) => {
  console.log('authenticated');
  localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken);
  this.lock.getProfile(authResult.idToken, (error, profile) => {
    if (error) {
      // Handle error
      return;
    }
    // Set the token and user profile in local storage
    localStorage.setItem('profile', JSON.stringify(profile));

    this.authenticated = true;
  });
});
this.lock.on('authorizaton_error', (error) => {
  // handle error when authorizaton fails
});
  },
  methods: {
    login() {
      this.lock.show();
    },
    logout() {
      // To log out, we just need to remove the token and profile
      // from local storage
      localStorage.removeItem('id_token');
      localStorage.removeItem('profile');
      this.authenticated = false;
    },
    getSecretThing() {
    var jwtHeader = { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('id_token') };
    this.$http.get('http://localhost:3001/secured/ping', (data) => {
      console.log(data);
      this.secretThing = data.text;
    }, {
      headers: jwtHeader
    }).error((err) => console.log(err));
  }
  },
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

**LOGIN.VUE**

```
<template>
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <h2>Logg inn bedrift</h2>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <form>
                    <div id="login-test">
                        <button @click="login()" class="btn btn-default" v-show="!authenticated">Login</button>
                        <button @click="logout()" class="btn btn-default" v-show="authenticated">Logout</button>
                        <button @click="getSecretThing()">Get Secret Thing</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
```

**INDEX.JS**

```
import Vue from "vue"
import Vuex from "vuex"
import api from '../api/index'
import * as types from './mutationtypes'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({ 
    state: {
        invoices: [],
        showHistory: false
    },
    actions: {
        getInvoices({ commit }) {
            api.getInvoices().then(invoices => commit(type.UPDATE_INVOICES, invoices))
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        [types.UPDATE_INVOICES] (state, invoices){ state.invoices = invoices },
        [types.UPDATE_INVOICE] (state, invoice) { state.invoice = invoice },
        [types.TOGGLE_SHOW_HISTORY] (state) {state.showHistory = !state.showHistory}
    }
 })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you have declared the method `login` on the root of your application and then tried to call it from a local component. The login method is therefore not in scope as Vue does not pass a parents methods to its children.

This is where `vuex` comes in as that offers up a global method `this.$store` which is available throughout your app and would allow you to call an action such as:

```
this.$store.dispatch('login')
```

Alternatively move your data, ready & methods params into `login.vue` and that should work as expected.

---

You also need to move: `lock: new Auth0Lock('xxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxx.eu.auth0.com')` out of your data as the data store is reactive and therefore should not contain functions/instances etc... Instead move this to the top level of your `login.vue` component, i.e.

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      authenticated: false,
      secretThing: '',
    }
  },
  lock: new Auth0Lock('xxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxx.eu.auth0.com'),
  ready() {
  ...
```

and call it via: `this.$options.lock`

Also note how your data now needs to become a function and return an object because it is no longer in the root of your application.

Comment: Thanks a bunch :) I Already tried to move the stuff from app.js into login.vue but got some issues (in the example showing the routing example) with a duplicate APP declaration.. 

Any chance you can show me where i should put the content inside mye VUE file(s) ? It's kinda new territory for me at the moment and my head is spinning when it comes to this.. (yet!) :)

Comment: Just updated the question with index.js which has the store functionality. (vuex)

Comment: Yeah I don't think you're calling the action or using the state yet though so the vuex isn't too vital to get the login component together: https://bitbucket.org/snippets/thebigsurf/nnqrj there's a snippet for it. If you need to you could refactor those methods to sit in your vuex, as a state for `authenticated` will likely be pretty handy.

Comment: I will check tomorrow morning :) Been really busy with indoor painting today *urkh!*.. not fun... :)

Comment: Thanks a bunch @GuyC :) it worked quite well, except that i have some issues with the redirectUrl.. It's set in the Allowed redirects, but it ends up with an url looking like this : http://localhost:8080/home?code=ldMEn7ekc4vvb9EH
..... when i type http://localhost:8080/home?code=ldMEn7ekc4vvb9EH#/home it goes the right place aka /home

...Think i have to implement routing here :)

Comment: Hmm.. and the login "button" is displayed all the time. the VUE chrome addon shows Auth0 as <Anonymous Component> with authenticated: false even after i have logged in. The "Lock" seems to work and shows "last time you logged in as....", so that thing appears to be working properly.

Comment: not 100% sure I follow :) Did this help you fix it / answer the question?

Comment: I managed to solve it.... Problem is that Vue 2.0 doesn't have the ready lifecycle event.. only Vue 1.0 got that one :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple, so happy days for you.

You do not have your login method in Vue component and this is causing you an issue. Vue is looking for `login()` method in `Login.vue` component, which I can't understand - you moved to `main.js`

You have to separate component logic and auth logic as well.

https://auth0.com/blog/create-an-app-in-vuejs-2/ (go really down).
Auth0 tutorial is showing all auth related functions stored in separate `auth.js` file.

Not going too much into details which you can easily get from that tutorial,
here you have script part which is missing from your `Login.vue`

```
<script>
  // Import the Lock instance
  import {lock} from '../index'

  export default {

    ready() {

      lock.on("authenticated", function(authResult) {
          lock.getProfile(authResult.idToken, function(error, profile) {

            if (error) {
              // handle error
              return;
            }

            localStorage.setItem('profile', JSON.stringify(profile))
            localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken)

          });
      });

    },

    methods: {

      login() {

        // Show the lock widget
        lock.show();

      },

      logout() {

        // Remove the profile and token from localStorage
        localStorage.removeItem('profile');
        localStorage.removeItem('id_token');

      }
    }

  }

  </script>
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your answer.. I see that i miss this functionality now. I just updated my question with my store functionality.. I'm still reading and trying to figure out exactly how VUE works so would it be possible to ask you for help on where and how to put the code inside my existing project ? It's kinda confusing compared to knockout/angular etc etc :)

Comment: Vue component can/should contain: template, style and script. All functions and data which you are using in your particular component should be placed in this component as long as functionality is not shared (that's why you can use Vuex store to keep shared data and simpel JS files to share common funcitonality which you are using across all components.